# MongoDB .NET Driver - How to increment double nested field

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-update

The goal: to increment double nested field with the specific identifier in the entity.

[image: mongo entity]

The example of the document here:

competition_dota2

```
{
    "id" : "b350c9fd-3632-4b0a-b5cb-66e41d530f55",
    "type" : "COMPETITION_TYPE_ESPORTDOTA2",
    "status_type" : "COMPETITION_STATUS_TYPE_WAITING",
    "start_time" : 
    {
        "seconds": "60",
         "nanos": 928852400
    },
    "coefficient_groups" : 
    [
        {
            "id" : "b350c9fd-3632-4b0a-b5cb-66e41d530f55",
            "name" : "winner",
            "type" : "OUTCOME_GROUP_TYPE_ONE_WINNER",
            "coefficients" : 
            [
                    {
                        "id" : "b350c9fd-3632-4b0a-b5cb-66e41d530f55",
                        "description" : "team1 won",
                        "rate" : 1.2,
                        "status_type" : "COEFFICIENT_STATUS_TYPE_ACTIVE",
                        "amount" : 0,
                        "probability" : 50
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "3c203bd7-2d7e-4937-a82a-e451cedf2ba8",
                        "description" : "team2 won",
                        "rate" : 0,
                        "status_type" : "COEFFICIENT_STATUS_TYPE_ACTIVE",
                        "amount" : 0,
                        "probability" : 50
                    }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "team1_id" : "b350c9fd-3632-4b0a-b5cb-66e41d530f55",
    "team2_id" : "b350c9fd-3632-4b0a-b5cb-66e41d530f55",
    "team1_kill_amount" : 0,
    "team2_kill_amount" : 0,
    "total_time" : 
    {
        "seconds": "60",
         "nanos": 928852400
    }
}
```

I'm trying to increment the "Amount" field.
For that, I'm using specific identifiers for both nested fields.
Is it enough to create find option for the top model only?

```cs
var competitionIdstring = competitionId.ToString();
var сoefficientIdstring = сoefficientId.ToString();

var filterBuilder = Builders<CompetitionDota2Entity>.Filter;
var updateBuilder = Builders<CompetitionDota2Entity>.Update;

var filterCompetitionId = filterBuilder.Eq(x => x.Id, competitionId.ToString());

var update = Builders<CompetitionDota2Entity>.Update;
var incAmount = update.Inc(
    "CompetitionDota2Entity.CoefficientGroups.$.Coefficients.$.Amount",
    amount);

var existingCoefficientGroup = await _collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
                    filterCompetitionId,
                    incAmount,
                    _defaultCompetitionDota2EntityFindOption,
                    token);
```

Comment: Would be great if you can share the sample document as JSON snippet instead of image. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to works with the update with `$[<identifier>]` filtered positional operator in order to update the element in the nested arrays.

**With MongoDB .NET Driver v2.16 and above**

In MongoDB .NET Driver v2.16 release, it offers the feature of [Implement positional update operators in LINQ3](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-4079?jql=project%20%3D%20CSHARP%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%202.16.0).

*Pre-requisites:*

Enable `LinqProvider.V3` in `MongoClientSettings`.

```cs
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(
    mongoUri
);
settings.LinqProvider = MongoDB.Driver.Linq.LinqProvider.V3;
```

```cs
var update = Builders<CompetitionDota2Entity>.Update;
var incAmount = update.Inc(x => x.CoefficientGroups.AllMatchingElements("cg")
    .Coefficients.AllMatchingElements("c").Amount,
    amount);

FindOneAndUpdateOptions<CompetitionDota2Entity> _defaultCompetitionDota2EntityFindOption = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<CompetitionDota2Entity>
{
    ArrayFilters = new ArrayFilterDefinition[]
    {
        new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<CoefficientGroup>
        (
            new BsonDocument("cg._id", competitionIdstring)
        ),
        new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<Coefficient> 
        (
            new BsonDocument("c._id", сoefficientIdstring)
        )
    }
};

var existingCoefficientGroup = await _collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
                    filterCompetitionId,
                    incAmount,
                    _defaultCompetitionDota2EntityFindOption,
                    token);
```

---

**With MongoDB .NET Driver v2.16 before**

```cs
var incAmount = update.Inc(
    "coefficient_groups.$[cg].coefficients.$[c].amount",
    amount);

FindOneAndUpdateOptions<CompetitionDota2Entity> _defaultCompetitionDota2EntityFindOption = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<CompetitionDota2Entity>
{
    ArrayFilters = new ArrayFilterDefinition[]
    {
        new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<CoefficientGroup>
        (
            new BsonDocument("cg._id", competitionIdstring)
        ),
        new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<Coefficient> 
        (
            new BsonDocument("c._id", сoefficientIdstring)
        )
    }
};
```

> Demo

[image]